# Exclude generic from union type in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a union type as follows:

```
type countries = "USA" | "Canada" | "UK" | "Australia" | string;
```

I'd like to remove the `string` from this union, so that only the string literals remain.

Ideally, it would be agnostic to the string literals (as opposed to using something like Pick<T, K>), so that the values can be updated at the parent.
I've already tried both the Omit and Exclude utility types, with no luck.

Is this possible?

Comment: You cannot - `type countries` is of a type `string` exclusively, string literal types are lost at that moment.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible. The type
`"USA" | "Canada" | "UK" | "Australia" | string`
is a string. So there is nothing to exclude or pick.

[image]

`type countries = string` and `type countries = "USA" | "Canada" | "UK" | "Australia" | string;` are both the same type string

You have to remove the string type to create a union of literal types:

```
type countries = "USA" | "Canada" | "UK" | "Australia";
```